# Is there any way to adapt an interface to Object properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having the following interfaces:

```
 export interface ObjectX {
   key: string,
   title: string,
   data: Record<string, unknown>;
}

export interface ObjectY {
     name: string,
     security: number,
     integrity: number,
}
```

And then the objects:

```
 const objectX: ObjectX = {
       key: 'generic_data',
       title: 'Generic Data',
       data: {
         name: 'Generic Data',
         security: 50,
         integrity: 10,
       },
    }

let objectY: ObjectY = {
   name: 'Specific Data',
   security: 10,
   integrity: 25,
}
```

Now, if I want to set the ObjectY with ObjectX data, I've to do the following:

```
objectY = objectX.data as any
```

**Note: not always objectX.data === ObjectY Interface, I want to set like a dynamic type that adapts to current object properties.**

I'd like to achieve this as long as objectY and ObjectX.data have the same properties:

objectY = objectX.data

Is it possible just with an interface??
Thank you very much in advantage

Comment: You should do it as `objectY = objectX.data as ObjectY;`

Comment: Yeah, but is there any way to handle it with just the interface?

Comment: I think use a generic interface should do it, just make the `data` be of the type passed in as I show in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make ObjectX a generic type

```
export interface ObjectX<TData> {
   key: string,
   title: string,
   data: TData;
}
```

This way you can use it with any type:

```
export interface ObjectY {
     name: string,
     security: number,
     integrity: number,
}

let myXObject: ObjectX<ObjectY>;
let myYObject: ObjectY = myXObject.data;
```